# Fixed width in Emacs term-mode

Tags: emacs

I've been using term-mode (called by `(term)`) more frequently lately
to run some shell subprocesses, and something is bothering me.

The problem is that some of these processes have a text UI, and they
interact very poorly with Emacs' constantly varying window sizes. Is
there a way to set a fixed width/height for the term subprocess? The
actual window width doesn't have to be fixed, I just want the shell
subprocess to work with constant dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the definition of `term-window-width` like so:

```
(defun term-window-width () 80)
```

This won't affect the size of the emacs window, but the term process will always think the window is 80 columns wide.  You may also want to turn on line truncation in your `term-mode-hook`:

```
(add-hook 'term-mode-hook
      (lambda () (setq truncate-lines t)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely certain, but I suspect that the behavior you're asking for isn't possible, at least not with generic `term`. You can (at least partially) fix the dimensions of Emacs windows (q.v., the `window-size-fixed` variable), but if the window does for any reason get resized, there's no method I know of to prevent `term` from updating the `$COLUMNS` and `$LINES` environment variables to reflect the new window dimensions. On the other hand, if you were to use `shell`, rather than `term`, you could `export` whatever values you wanted for `$COLUMNS` and `$LINES` and they would persist throughout the session. If my understanding of your preferred configuration is correct, your best option might be to use `shell` inside of a window with fixed size, so that ncurses-based apps will maintain a constant size, while ordinary output will simply be wrapped or scrolled by the buffer as per usual. Alternatively, you might investigate the `multi-term` package; I've seen it recommended by others in the past, though I can't vouch for it personally.

Edit: scratch what I said about using `shell`. It's been a long time since I've used it at all; forgot that it doesn't generally support most ncurses-based programs. Sorry.